# Dent in rear passenger door

Tags: car, dent

[image]

I've this dent on rear passenger door of my car. What would be the best and cheapest way to fix or reduce it ?

Comment: Get a second hand door in the same color from a breaker yard cheapest option...

Comment: Can something be done on the same door ? like using plunger or dent puller ?

Comment: Think about those sharp creases...

Comment: Unfortunately that's well out of the "paintless" dent repair range.  Dare I say, you could live with it?

Comment: Hmm, how about "It's Dad's car and needs to be fixed before he gets back from holiday"....

Answer (score 2):

Options available, from cheapest upwards:

1 get a secondhand door in same color from breakers

2 as 1 but spray to change color

3 remove dents and fill, sand to proper finish then spray door

4 fit new outer door skin sand and spray...

5 complete new door assembly fit, sand and spray...

Time could be an issue - quality work takes time, paint takes time to dry etc

Comment: You might want to add electromagnetic dent removal to your list, it may be able to smooth that out.

Comment: @GdD There are many techniques for removing dents : suction cups, pullers using drilled holes or welded strips to point out some, but I don’t think an electromagnetic dent remover will get rid of that crease...

Comment: A good smart-repair guy could probably reduce that dent to a level where some might find it acceptable to leave that way. As far as we can see there is no paint missing. So this would could still be the cheapest Option. (depending on used door prices)

Comment: @Daniel and any good smart-repair guys are always cheap... A door from a breakers could still be cheaper...

Comment: @Solar Mike: Sure, all depends on the market, as I said :) I just think it would complete your post to add that option. Doors are mostly easily disassembled so a smart-repair can work from the inside, which helps not hurting the paint in the "un-denting" process

Comment: How much you folks think a full door would cost at a junk yard? No more than $250?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. Actually, I am planning to but this car. It has 78400 miles on it. It has got no mechanical problems, only concern was these dents. I am getting this car for $3500. I’ve to use it for 5-6 months. All i want to know is if it’s a good deal or not. Or I should ignore it as resale value would be too less because of these dents and investing $1000 to fix it would be waste.

Comment: We don't do purchasing questions - how can we assess the value of a car? If it will do what you need buy it- if not then don't...